# Jquery file upload in django not uploading files

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am using [Jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) for my django application. I have copied the files exactly what it was there in the above link. The problem is when I select the file its not showing thumbnail on the page and when i click on upload it returns the below output on the page (not even on my template). I checked the database, everytime i click on upload files a record is creating.

```
[{"url": "http://localhost:8090/media/pictures/Hydrangeas.jpg", "thumbnail_url":
 "http://localhost:8090/media/pictures/Hydrangeas.jpg", 
 "name": "Hydrangeas.jpg", 
 "delete_type": "DELETE", "delete_url": "/delete/19"}]
```

I dont know what could be the problem. Any one have the same problem? Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of bootstrap css files. I solved it myself. There are so many css files which made it not to work. After cleaning them. It worked properly.